# QuitApplication Button on unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a Quit button in Unity, but when I add my script to the button and click it, it doesn't quit.

Here is my C# script:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Quit_App : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnClick() {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

I have created it and assigned to the canvas using the UI, and I use the `Button(Script)` box in order to execute this code using the `OnClick()` box.
There, I selected it as `object MyButton` and the `Quit_App()` function using a string name.

Comment: Add `using UnityEngine.UI;` at the top, this may help

Answer (score 2):

Your script assumes that calling the method OnClick will magically make the click detected, but that is not the case.

You need a Menu Manager script added to the scene exposing a public method to be binded to the Button component.

Here the setup you need:
[image: Button setup]

The script MenuManager is attached to the MenuManager game object:
[image: Menu Manager Setup]

The code in the MenuManager script is real simple:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MenuManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public void ExitNow()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

}
```

I uploaded the package with a [fully functional implementation here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17VFcmjz0FFkSAksXm4jKRB7KY-BklsCj/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

First, this answer assumes that your code works and the only problem is that the `Application.Quit ()` command does not execute.

The `Application.Quit ()` command does not work when testing the application in the **Unity Editor** (for example, by pressing the "Play" button). It would close the **Unity Editor**.

To test, go to the "Files / Build and Run" menu.

This will build and execute the project and `Application.Quit()` will be execute properly.

Answer (score 0):

After a search I found that onclick not a member of MonoBehaviour look at OnMouseDown on the following link http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Comment: it didnt work on the second try of this script that you posted

Comment: this method OnClick which line will call it?

Answer (score 0):

I find a semi-solution for this problem.I used this script that allows me to exit when i press the escape button.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
            Application.Quit();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
            Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean exit Play Mode thats completely an other thing. because quit is only when its built into an app.

Quitting the app:

```
Application.Quit();
```

Quitting the play mode:

```
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
```